# Use data-attributes to reduce markup

Tags: jquery, json, html, jquery-animate

I have two animations which are practically identical... the difference between them is "left vs right" positioning. I would like to reuse the first block of code for both .forward and .backward... I'm guessing this could be done with the use of a HTML 5 data- attributes or maybe variables, but I'm not sure how to go about that.

```
  .hover-area { position:relative; width:100%; height:50px; }
  .backward, .forward { position:absolute; }
  .backward{ left:0px; }
  .forward { right:0px; }​


  <div class="hover-area">
      Hover Area
      <div class="backward" data-animate-on='{"left":"20"}' data-animate-off='{"left":"0"}'>Previous</div>
      <div class="forward" data-animate-on='{"right":"20"}' data-animate-off='{"right":"0"}'>Next</div>
  </div>


    $('.forward').css({opacity:0, right:0});
    $('.hover-area').hover(function() {
        $(this).find('.forward').stop()
            .animate({right:20}, {queue:false, duration:300, easing:'easeOutCubic'})
            .animate({opacity:'0.95'}, {queue:false, duration:400, easing:'easeOutCubic'});
    },function() {
        $(this).find('.forward').stop()
            .animate({right:0}, {queue:false, duration:550, easing:'easeOutSine'})
            .animate({opacity:'0'}, {queue:false, duration:300, easing:'easeOutSine'});
    });




    $('.backward').css({opacity:0, left:0});
    $('.hover-area').hover(function() {
        $(this).find('.backward').stop()
            .animate({left:20}, {queue:false, duration:300, easing:'easeOutCubic'})
            .animate({opacity:'0.95'}, {queue:false, duration:400, easing:'easeOutCubic'});
    },function() {
        $(this).find('.backward').stop()
            .animate({left:0}, {queue:false, duration:550, easing:'easeOutSine'})
            .animate({opacity:'0'}, {queue:false, duration:300, easing:'easeOutSine'});
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) function to obtain the data-attributes and use them in `.animate()`:

```
$('.backward,.forward').css({opacity:0, right:0});
    $('.hover-area').hover(function() {
        $(this).find('.backward,.forward').stop()
            .animate($(this).data("animate-on"), {queue:false, duration:300, easing:'easeOutCubic'})
            .animate({opacity:'0.95'}, {queue:false, duration:400, easing:'easeOutCubic'});
    },function() {
        $(this).find('.backward,.forward').stop()
            .animate($(this).data("animate-off"), {queue:false, duration:550, easing:'easeOutSine'})
            .animate({opacity:'0'}, {queue:false, duration:300, easing:'easeOutSine'});
    });
```

Here's a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/D2tCd/)**.​

Comment: it just fades in and out... it also need to shift from left to right and visa versa... thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a good candidate for CSS3 transform animations.  Add a single class `forward` or `backward`, without all the data attributes, and use CSS to specify the animation properties.

```
.goforward {
    left: 20px;
    transition-property: left;
    transition-duration: 3s;
}
```

Then just add/remove the class to begin the animation:

```
$(".forward").addClass("goforward");
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/EMUcV/1/

Comment: Once I remembered the vendor prefixes, I realized this isn't exactly a *shortcut*.  But it is if you're using Sass or another CSS compiler, which everyone should be!